# How to use the Click event in a GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, how can you fire an event when a GridViewColumn is clicked?

I have many `GridViewColumns` like this; i want, when user clicks on it, show an update form to update some data.
How i can do that?

```
        <GridViewColumn util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Username" >
            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Width="130" Height="25" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Username" Foreground="Black" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Height="30" Margin="7,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Username}" Foreground="Black" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` is not actually a Control in WPF. It is one of the view modes for a `ListView` control. You can find the documentation of the `GridView` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752213.aspx.

So I think you may want `MouseDoubleClick` event of `ListView` to implement your desired behavior. This can be done as below.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```